# How to access Array within Array within Array while dealing with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, enums

Here is the NSLog of my Structure (Each enum is a custom tableViewCell). I need to be able to show each cell in my table view.-

```
(
    (
    0,
    0
),
    (
    4
),
    (
    1,
            (
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        ),
                    (
            2
        )
    )
),
    (
    4
)
)
```

As you can see, it is an Array with 4 Array objects. Within these objects are enums, or arrays with enums. [0] has an array with two 0 enums, [1] has an array with one 4 enum, [2] has an array with one 1 enum, AND an array of arrays within that has eight enums of 2.

My question is how do I display these cells in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

BucketListCellType type = [[[[self.presentedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

}
```

is getting me an error - `[__NSCFNumber objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Here is where I am constructing that array -

```
-(void)showPresentedCells
{ 

NSMutableArray *preCells = [NSMutableArray new];

// First Section - Suggested Bucket List Images

NSMutableArray *suggestedBucketListImages = [NSMutableArray new];

[suggestedBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCellWithAddToBucketList)];
[suggestedBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCellWithAddToBucketList)];

[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:suggestedBucketListImages]];

// Second Section - Top Bucket List Images

NSMutableArray *topBucketListImages = [NSMutableArray new];

[topBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCell)];

[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:topBucketListImages]];

// Third Section - My Bucket List Images

NSMutableArray *myBucketListCategories = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *categoryWithPictures = [NSMutableArray new];

[myBucketListCategories addObject:@(CreateNewBucketListCell)];

for (int i = 0; i <= [self.bucketListCategories count]; i++) {

    [categoryWithPictures addObject:@[@(CategoryCell)]];

}

[myBucketListCategories addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:categoryWithPictures]];

[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:myBucketListCategories]];


NSMutableArray *unorganizedBucketListImages = [NSMutableArray new];

[unorganizedBucketListImages addObject:@(mainPhotoCell)];
[preCells addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:unorganizedBucketListImages]];

self.presentedCells = preCells;

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you need to provide more info. How many rows do you have ? USe breakpoints and do debugging. At somepoint you will end accessing an array instead of an integer.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to show in a particular row of your table. I would have guessed that you wanted this top level array to be the array of sections, and that the sub arrays would be the items within that section, but I don't understand what you want to with the second item in the third array third one, whose value is, itself, yet another array.

Comment: Each enum is a tableviewCell

Comment: Yeah, but table views generally are used to show two levels of structure, sections and rows. But your data structure has three levels of structure, so I'm trying to understand how you want to visually represent that.

Comment: I am trying to add a cell underneath the [2] enum when tapped and remove it when deselected.

Comment: You need to flatten the data structure to be *table like*.  I.e. a top-level array which represents the rows of the table (or array of array if you have sections).  Each element of this array must contain all the information required to "render" (populate) each table cell.  This is probably best done with a custom object, as generally, everything is best done with a custom object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is that you're doing calling `objectAtIndex` for three levels of arrays, but that will work only where you really have three levels of structure (e.g. section `2`, row `1`). Everywhere else you only have two levels of structure (returning a `NSNumber`) and trying to call `objectAtIndex` with that will yield the error you describe.

What's less clear to me is what you want to show when there is only two levels of structure. But you could presumably do something like:

```
BucketListCellType type;
id object = self.presentedCells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    type = [object[0] intValue];
} else {
    type = [object intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I went back to the 2 levels of structure for the array. The key line is here: 

     for (int i = 0; i <= [self.bucketListCategories count]; i++) {
        
        [myBucketListCategories addObject:@(CategoryCell)];
        
     }

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you have different levels of nesting of structure, so you either have to fix the structure to have a consistent level of nesting or have the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` conditionally format it like shown above.